# ESPCAM and ESP32 data gets sent and comes back empty with ESPNOW

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32, microprocessors

I have a project with espcam and esp32 and I need to transfer data from the espcam to the esp32 using ESPNOW. I discovered that I need to have the same channel on both of the processors. I changed it to the same channel and the data is successfully delivered, but comes empty.

Code:

**Sender (espcam)**:

```cpp
uint8_t broadcastAddress1[] = {assume its the right one here :)}; //Enter your Receiver board MAC Address

String mess;
typedef struct test_struct {
  int a;
} test_struct;

test_struct test;

esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;


// callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  char macStr[18];
  Serial.print("Packet to: ");
  // Copies the sender mac address to a string
  snprintf(macStr, sizeof(macStr), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
           mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2], mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
  Serial.print(macStr);
  Serial.print(" send status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  Serial.println();

  //ESPNOW
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial); // Uncomment to verify channel number before
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
  esp_wifi_set_channel(3, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial); // Uncomment to verify channel change after

  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
   
  // register peer
  peerInfo.channel = 0;  
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;
  // register first peer  
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress1, 6);
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
  //ESPNOW

  esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(0, (uint8_t *) &test, sizeof(test_struct));
  
  test.a = 5;
  Serial.println(test.a);
  delay(1);
  if (result == ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Sent with success");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error sending the data");
  }
  delay(2000);
```

**Receiver (esp32)**:

```
typedef struct test_struct {
  int a;
} test_struct;

//Create a struct_message called myData
test_struct myData;

//callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  memcpy(&myData, incomingData, sizeof(myData));
  Serial.print("Bytes received: ");
  Serial.println(len);
  Serial.print("a: ");
  Serial.println(myData.a);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(myData.a);
}
Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial); // Uncomment to verify channel number before
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
  esp_wifi_set_channel(3, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
  WiFi.printDiag(Serial); // Uncomment to verify channel change after
  Serial.println(WiFi.channel());
  //Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  
  // Once ESPNow is successfully Init, we will register for recv CB to
  // get recv packer info
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
```

I tried changing the channel to the right one, and it helped to connect between them, but the data still comes in empty.

Comment: Why are you setting `test.a` to 5 *after* you send the data?

Comment: omg, im stupid... :)
ty :))))

Comment: You're not stupid :) Glad that was it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are setting the struct variable `test`'s attribute `a` to `5` only after you send the data.

Make sure to initialize the payload to what you want prior to sending.